# how do i change the text under a navigation menu

Tags: menus

More specifically this, it's rather annoying to see that twice, and more importantly I want to change that to a text of my choosing.
So I'm using a free wordpress theme named "Trident Lite" and that thing will appear under any category, post or page I add as a menu. 
[image]

Comment: add more info to this question we dont know what code is outputting that

Comment: looks like this is a page title or may be a breadcrumb link, please clear the question & add more explanation

Answer (score 0):

I see two rather 'quick' ways of doing this: either you hide what appears to be the page title by css, or you edit the page template accordingly. Both should be done in a child theme.

Hiding the title with a few lines of css would probably be the quicker, but also a bit dirtier way to do this. For example:

```
.entry-title {
    display: none;
}
```

You'll find an introduction to child themes [here at wordpress.org](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/).

Answer (score 0):

Open your content-page.php (you can find it in the folder ‘template-parts’)and remove or comment the following code:

```
<header class="entry-header">
    <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
</header><!-- .entry-header -->
```

let me know, any issue you found.